# Book(s) about warring families

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book over 20 years ago but I can't remember the title or author. It may have been the first of a series, at least I think it was written that way but I don't know if there were any others published.

It's a far future/scifi novel with no magical element. There were two rich, powerful families, the eldest sons of which end up fighting (physically, not just verbally). The son of the 'evil' family uses drugs to enhance his speed and strength, as well as using them recreationally. I think there was also a girl, possibly who falls in love with the 'good' eldest son but who's supposed to marry the 'evil' one.

For a while I thought this was "Sword of the Lamb" by M.K.Wren, but when I finally found a copy I realised it was quite different. It's definitely not Dune! I realise there's not much to go on, but the use of drugs by the 'evil' scion was quite prominent.

Comment: Dune - Frank Herbert? But this sounds like a pretty broad trope.

Comment: *Dune* is by far the most prominent story along those lines, but you're right, there really are a lot of stories using those elements. We'd really need more information to narrow it down more.

Comment: There are surely hundreds of books that fit this description. What else do you remember? For example, what kind of environment was it — medieval, Renaissance, industrial age, near future, far future? Apart from these drugs, was there magic or other supernatural phenomena?

Comment: When you say it's not Dune, do you mean not any of the Dune books *including* those by his son? This sounds vaguely like the [Dune: House <blah>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_House_Atreides) books.

Comment: This sounds like Generic Sci-Fi the series.

Comment: It's not any of the Dune books!

Comment: Some of this sounds like the [Deathstalker series by Simon R. Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker_(series)).